# How do you add “open in terminal” to the right-click mouse menu for folders/directories for caja?

Tags: linux, mouse, file-manager, menu, caja

I know about that [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117452/how-do-you-add-open-in-terminal-to-the-right-click-mouse-menu-for-folders-dire), but how to do this in caja ?

Comment: I installed "caja-open-terminal"...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, thank you. How to do it manually, without installation ?

Comment: First you find the source code, then you type it all out, then you compile it, then you copy the files to the appropriate place.

Comment: Oh, I thought just by adding a few lines in a file.

Answer (score 6):

## First method

Installing caja-open-terminal via :

```
sudo apt-get install caja-open-terminal
```

After type in terminal :

```
caja -q
```